# Entity Framework Code First -- Generating a Database from a Class

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I just started working with Entity Framework in C# and I'm running up against a problem using the code-first methodology in my test project. I'm trying to generate a database from my Character Class, but I keep getting the following exception :

'*The invocation of the constructor on type 'EFTesting.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'*

I have previously finished a EF code-first tutorial using [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx), but with this current WPF project, I'm confused as to why my code breaks.

Here's my Character Class:

```
public class Character 
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public CharacterClass Character_Class { get; set; }
    public Gender _Gender { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Inventory { get; set; }

    //Navigation property 
    public virtual Character Contact { get; set; }
}
```

In my main window, I am adding Characters to a Collection, then binding this collection to my ComboBox. Below that, I am adding the Characters to the Contact database.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        squad_members.Add(new Character() {ID = 1, Name = "Wacken", Level = 8, Character_Class = CharacterClass.Mage, _Gender = Gender.Male, Inventory = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item("Gerrund Wand", "Magical Direction", 656, "Witcher Magical Wand", true ), new Item("Velcro Whip", "Whips your face off", 12, "Annoying as hell", true ), new Item("Invisibility Cloak", "Invisibility", 900, "Cloak of Invisibility", true)} });
        squad_members.Add(new Character() {ID = 2,  Name = "Vrigun", Level = 4, Character_Class = CharacterClass.Mage, _Gender = Gender.Female,  Inventory = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item("Satanic Girdings", "Demonic Protection", 6660, "Clothing protects user from attack", true ), new Item("Viper Staff", "Poisons Enemy Resolve", 860, "Bites and Kills Everything", true ), new Item("Baal Mask", "Infects enemy mind", 6660, "Possesses User's Opponents", false ) }});

        Binding comboBinding = new Binding();
        comboBinding.Source = squad_members;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(Character_ComboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, comboBinding);


        addToDataBase();
    }

    public void addToDataBase()
    {
        // DB BINDING
        using (var db = new CharacterContext())
        {
            //fails right here
            db.Contacts.Add(new Character() { ID = 1, Name = "Wacken", Level = 8, Character_Class = CharacterClass.Mage, _Gender = Gender.Male, Strength = 6, Intelligence = 9, Dexterity = 3, Gold = 1255, Inventory = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item("Gerrund Wand", "Magical Direction", 656, "Witcher Magical Wand", true), new Item("Velcro Whip", "Whips your face off", 12, "Annoying as hell", true), new Item("Invisibility Cloak", "Invisibility", 900, "Cloak of Invisibility", true) } });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Also, my CharacterContext Class that goes with the DB:

```
public class CharacterContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Character> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

My Intent is to create a database of characters. Is there something I am doing wrong? If so what are some suggestions to fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** I added the method  addToDatabase() that is supposed to add a test Character to the database. I debugged it from here and the program fails when it hits the db.Contacts.Add(). Any Ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: For starters, don't do DB ops in your constructor. Second, try putting the DB operations in a try/catch block and seeing what the exception actually is. I'm guessing you have duplicate records, or the database hasn't been created yet.

Comment: by "DB ops in your constructor", do you mean the / public DbSet<Character> Contacts { get; set; } / in the CharacterContext Class?

Comment: No, I mean don't connect to or execute commands on, a database in a constructor. Thats not what its used for.

Comment: debugging the program fails at the db.Contacts.Add() method.

Comment: Ok, and what exception is generated, what is the inner exception? Catch and log it, this is how you debug code in the real world.